# Nodejs Passport display username

Tags: node.js, passport.js

In nodeJS I am using the passport module for authentication. I would like to show the username of the currently logged in user.

I tried the following code:

```
passport.displayName
```

and

```
Localstrategy.username
```

And for more info please also see:
http://passportjs.org/docs/profile

But that is not working. Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 54, accepted):

The user (as supplied by the verify callback), is set as a property on the request at `req.user`.

Any properties of the user can be accessed through that object, in your case `req.user.username` and `req.user.displayName`.

If you're using Express, and want to expose the username as a variable within a template, that can be done when rendering:

```
app.get('/hello', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index.jade', { username: req.user.username });
});
```

Comment: I am using the following code for the login:

app.post('/login',
  passport.authenticate('local', { successRedirect: '/',
                                   failureRedirect: '/login' })
);

I am not able to acces the req.user.username on the '/' page. How can I acces it on that page?

Comment: Is `req.user` property available on that page?  If not, it sounds like  session support is not enabled.  Be sure to `app.use(passport.session())` middleware, as well as configure Express session middleware.  See the "Middleware" section of this page: http://passportjs.org/guide/configuration.html

Comment: how can I get access to the user information from socket.io? should I just save the user into some global variable when he first logs-in?

Comment: @vsync You can use passport.socketio for getting auth user info from socket.io - https://npmjs.org/package/passport.socketio

Comment: what verify callback?

Comment: the link is broken, this stuff changes every week

Answer (score 3):

I've created a simple view helper to have access to authentication status and user information

```
var helpers = {};

helpers.auth = function(req, res) {
    var map = {};
    map.isAuthenticated = req.isAuthenticated();
    map.user = req.user;
    return map;
}

app.dynamicHelpers(helpers);
```

After doing that you will be able to acess the object `auth` on your views, for example `auth.user.xxxx`.

Comment: How do you call this helper? And from where do you call it? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Helpers are not supported with Express v4.x

A good alternative is to create a middleware such as:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.locals.user = req.user;
    next();
});
```

Then you can use the "user" variable in your views.

Answer (score 1):

Routes Code -

```
router.get('/', ensureAuthenticated, function(req, res){
  res.render('administrator/dashboard',{title: 'Dashboard', user:req.user.username });
  console.log(req.user.username);
});
```

.ejs File Code -

```
Welcome:  <%= user %>
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help
req.session.passport.user