# NodeJS display username in view without res.render

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, passport.js

There is a good answer how to pass user info from req.user to the view [Nodejs Passport display username](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9218855/1821057). All the answers I've seen on the web including this one and also looking at [mean.io](http://mean.io) use jade rendering engine. In my case I am sending the file as is using res.sendfile(....static.html) with angular doing the routing.

What is the correct way to pass user info to the view in this case?

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem? Please let me know otherwise.
If it did, feel free to accept it. That helps you, me and the rest of the community :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep sending a static file and not using `res.render()`, you have to request the user information on your client-side, instead of passing it in by your server.

There are a couple of ways to request user details with Angular. The simplest is probably to do it from the controller needing the information:

```
// UserController.js
app.controller('UserController', function (UserService) {    
    UserService.resolveUser().success(function (user) {
        $scope.user = user;
    });    
});

// UserService.js
app.factory('UserService', function ($http) {    
    return {
        resolveUser: function() {            
            return $http.get('/user');
        },        
    }    
});
```

You can also use the [`resolve`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute.%24routeProvider#methods_when_parameters) method on `$routeProvider` to delay loading of the route until the user information is requested and available.

... or you can manually bootstrap your app, if you need the user information available on all routes.

*Let me know if you need additional information, either with Angular or with Node.js, which I haven't touched here.*

**Edit:**

In regard to your comment, this is how you could use $http to request your user information and only then bootstrap your app:

```
angular.module('app', []);

// We only need invoke in order to use the $http service
// before we are bootstrapped.
angular.bootstrap().invoke(function ($http) {

    $http.get('user.json').success(function (data) {
        angular.element(document).ready(function () {
            angular.module('app').constant('USER', data);
            angular.bootstrap(document, ['app']);
        });
    });

});

angular.module('app').run(function (USER) {
    console.log(USER);
});
```

You can find a live example with [this Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Z68IBp?p=preview).

Comment: how would you manually bootstrap the app? I think that is what I was looking for. Thanks

Comment: I will have to check this out when I have time but thanks a lot for the help!