# Node.js Passport Display username after successful login

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js

I am using Node.js Passport and I'm trying to figure out how to display username after a successful login. After reading the documentation I've verified that i have Sessions and Middleware configured which is what I need but what are my next steps?

This is my **users.js** file:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

var User = require('../models/user');

// Home
router.get('/index', function(req, res){
    res.render('index');
});
// Profile
router.get('/profile', function(req, res){
    res.render('profile');
});
// Register
router.get('/register', function(req, res){
     res.render('register');
});

// Login
router.get('/login', function(req, res){
    res.render('login');
});

// About-us
router.get('/about-us', function(req, res){
    res.render('about-us');
});


// Register User
router.post('/register', function(req, res){
var email = req.body.email;
var username = req.body.username;
var password = req.body.password;

// Validation
req.checkBody('username', 'Username is Required').notEmpty();
req.checkBody('email', 'Email is required').notEmpty();
req.checkBody('email', 'Email is not valid').isEmail();
req.checkBody('password', 'Password is required').notEmpty();

var errors = req.validationErrors();

if(errors){
    res.render('register',{
        errors:errors   
    });
} else {
    var newUser = new User({
        email:email,
        username: username,
        password: password,
    });

    User.createUser(newUser, function(err, user){
        if(err) throw err;
        console.log(user);
    });

    req.flash('success_msg', 'You are now registered. Log In!');
    res.redirect('/users/login');
}
});

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
function(username, password, done) {
User.getUserByUsername(username, function(err, user){
if(err) throw err;
if(!user){
    return done(null, false, {message: 'User does not exist!'});
}

User.comparePassword(password, user.password, function(err, isMatch){
    if(err) throw err;
    if(isMatch){
        return done(null, user);
    } else {
        return done(null, false, {message: 'Invalid password'});
    }
    });
    });
    }));

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
 done(null, user.id);
  });

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
 User.getUserById(id, function(err, user) {
  done(err, user);
});
});


router.post('/login',
passport.authenticate('local', {successRedirect:'/users/profile',      failureRedirect:'/users/login',failureFlash: true}),
function(req, res) {
res.redirect('/users/profile')

});

router.get('/logout', function(req, res){
req.logout();

req.flash('success_msg', '');

res.redirect('/');
});

module.exports = router;
```

And this is my **app.js** file:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var exphbs = require('express-handlebars');
var expressValidator = require('express-validator');
var flash = require('connect-flash');
var session = require('express-session');
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var mongo = require('mongodb');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
 mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/loginandregister');
 var db = mongoose.connection;

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

// Init App
var app = express();

// View Engine
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.engine('handlebars', exphbs({defaultLayout:'layout'}));
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');

// BodyParser Middleware
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());

// Set Static Folder
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use('/public', express.static('public'));

// Express Session
app.use(session({
    secret: 'secret',
    saveUninitialized: true,
    resave: true
}));

// Passport init
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

// Express Validator
app.use(expressValidator({
  errorFormatter: function(param, msg, value) {
    var namespace = param.split('.')
      , root    = namespace.shift()
      , formParam = root;

while(namespace.length) {
  formParam += '[' + namespace.shift() + ']';
}
return {
  param : formParam,
  msg   : msg,
  value : value
 };
 }
 }));

// Connect Flash
app.use(flash());

// Global Vars
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.locals.success_msg = req.flash('success_msg');
  res.locals.error_msg = req.flash('error_msg');
  res.locals.error = req.flash('error');
  res.locals.user = req.user || null;
  next();
});



app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);

// Set Port
app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 3000));

app.listen(app.get('port'), function(){
    console.log('Server started on port '+app.get('port'));
});
```

I've read a similar question on the site and the answer stated that:

```
app.get('/example', function(req, res) {
res.render('index', { username: req.user.username });
});
```

needs to be implemented. But I am confused as to where and how? I tried placing it into to my users.js file but i get a "ReferenceError: app is not defined" error in terminal when restarting the node app.
What are my next steps? Any and every help is valued and appreciated. Thank you.

EDIT:

I added

```
router.get('/profile', function(req, res){
res.render('profile', { username: req.user.username });
});
```

to my users.js file and added:

```
<header>
  <h1>Hello?</h1>
  {{#if user}}
    <p>Hello {{username}}</p>
  {{else}}
    <p>Please <a href='/users/login'>Log In</a></p>
  {{/if}}
 </header>
```

to my profile.handlebars page but still no username display. What am i missing???

**SOLUTION:** Apparently my code was correct and my problem was solved hours ago however it was hiding in plain site. I am using Firefox to build my site and Chrome to conduct all my research and web searching. After DEEP searching i stumbled upon another similar question to my own and this guy complained that he had `<p>Hi, {{username}}</p>` within his index file but only `Hi` was showing up within his browser. On the contrary neither `Hi or {{username}}` was showing in my browser. My entire `<p>` tag was missing. So i simply loaded my site in Chrome and there it was problem solved! Bad practice on my part for only using one browser but that's what I get for silly mistakes :)

Comment: Change `app` to `router`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the rendering part of the mentioned part of this code:

```
app.get('/example', function(req, res) {
  res.render('index', { username: req.user.username });
});
```

i.e., `res.render('index', { username: req.user.username });` at the right/required path.

like you can try using it as

```
router.get('/profile', function(req, res){
  res.render('profile', { username: req.user.username });
});
```

and consume(use) the rendered variable `username` in your view for displaying.

If this doesn't work or you have some other problem, refer [Nodejs Passport display username](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9216185/nodejs-passport-display-username?rq=1) also.

Comment: Do i place it in my app.js file or my users.js file?

Comment: In the current code structure you are using `app.js` file for application configuration and `users.js` file for defining routes. So use it in `users.js` file.

Comment: I'm really fixed on figuring this out can you take a look at my edit and explain to me what i'm missing

Comment: Nevermind i figured it out but thank you. Good help!

Comment: you should also add the workaround which did the job so that it can help other people stuck with the same problem. anyways, good job!  :)

Comment: Thanks srishabh and my solution was rather embarrassing but I posted it anyways! :)

Answer (score 0):

My workaround was adding the req.user (if it exists, thus when loggedin) to the rendering. I've included both a hello, {{user}} and Dynamic navbar example.

I don't know if it's because I use handlebars instead of express-handelbars but the example I used to make this does not have to send the req.user object along for the render. It automatically sends it along? So I feel like my workaround is unnecesary if I do it right?

Edit: this solution only works for 1 page. If you go to another route it doesn't send the object along anymore.

Edit2: Apparently with express 4 sending the user object along in req.user is the only way I've found so far. But you'll have to send it along every route that requests data from the data base as well.

Confirmed edit 2 through this example: https://github.com/passport/express-4.x-local-example/blob/master/server.js

```
// Get Homepage
router.get('/', function(req,res){
  Job.find({})
    .exec(function(err, jobs){
      if(err){
        res.send('Error occured', err);
      } else {
        res.render('jobs', {jobs, user:req.user});
      }
    });
});


<nav>
      <ul class="nav nav-pills pull-right">
        {{#if user}}
      <li role="presentation"><span class="glyphicons glyphicons-user"></span><p style='color:white'>Hello {{user.name}}</p></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a href="/users/logout">Logout</a></li>
        {{else}}
          <li role="presentation"><a href="/users/login">Login</a></li>
          <li role="presentation"><a href="/users/register">Register</a></li>
        {{/if}}
      </ul>
    </nav>
```