# Passport.JS - Showing user data on view

Tags: node.js, passport.js

We're making our first node.js Q&A app and we are using **passport.js** as a register/login system.

I'm wondering if it's possible to acces data from the logged in user at a view?

For Example:

1. User registers
2. User logs in
3. User get's redirected to a list of questions (www.dev.com/topics) and **on this page we want to show the
   users First Name**

What do we need to do to make this happen?

We've tried several things but nothing seems to work.

***Here's my topic router***

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var Topic = require('../models/topicModel.js');

    router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
        res.render('create_topic.ejs', { title: 'Topics', user: req.user });
    });

    router.get('/id/:id', function(req, res, next) {

        var id = req.params.id;

        Topic.findOne({topicID: id}, function(err, doc){

            res.render('questions.ejs', {docs: doc});
        });
    });

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Yes, you can. Try the examples in npmjs.org/package/login-plus

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nodejs Passport display username](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9216185/nodejs-passport-display-username)